# Get multiple counts with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a statistics table.
The data table looks like this:

```
|value|
-------
|1    |
-------
|2    |
-------
|1    |
-------
|3    |
-------
```

Now, I want to count the number of rows at the value = 1, value = 2 and value = 3.

This is the output table I want to have

```
|value|count|
-------------
|1    |2    |
-------------
|2    |1    |
-------------
|3    |1    |
```

How can I write queries to get output like this? Thanks you.

Comment: select value, count(1) from tableA group by value

Comment: Explanation for Mido: You are looking for an aggregation of the table's rows. An aggregation gives you sums, minimumns, maximums, counts, etc. of the data. The aggregation function for counting is `COUNT`. There are two versions: 1) `COUNT(*)` to count rows, which is what you want. (2) `COUNT(expression)` to count non-null occurences of an expression. The constant expression `1` in `COUNT(1)` is never null, so while you are telling the DBMS that you want to count only certain rows, you will count them all. Better just tell the DBMS what you want it to do and use `COUNT(*)` right away...

Comment: At last an aggregation results in one total row, unless you tell the DBMS you want one result row per ___. "One result row per ___" translates to `GROUP BY ___` in SQL. You want one result row per value, so it's `GROUP BY value`. At the end you should add `ORDER BY value`, because you probably want your result rows ordered by value ( value 1 first, then value 2, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below - using `count()` and `group by`

```
select value, count(*)
from tablename
group by value
```

Comment: … plus `order by value` at the end to get the desired result order.